# Remap Super+w to up key

Tags: linux, command-line

I am using Linux mint 21.2 . My laptop up arrow is not working. Please guide to set(remap) Super+w as up key. I want to use it system wide specially with bash.

I have tried the following script by putting it as shortcut. But it does not work.

```
#!/bin/sh
xdotool key Up
```

Edit:

```
#!/bin/sh
#emulating up arrow
#sleep is to avoid overlap of pressed button and up arrow
sleep 0.2
xdotool key Up
```

This worked. But when launched with shortcuts like Ctrl+w, Ctrl+up_arrow gets pressed if ctrl is pressed for longer.

Any solution?

Comment: If the issue is the keyboard, it will be easier to replace the keyboard.

Comment: It's a laptop, hard to replace. Still I will, but for sometime I have to manage with it.

Comment: Look for Nordic Keyboards on Amazon and see if they have a fit.  I replaced the keyboard on my ThinkPad X230 that way - works great.